# Openstack-ansible setup-openstack.yml Error on Task [os_keystone: Create fernet keys for Keystone]

Tags: pip, ansible, openstack, lxc

can someone help me?, 
Openstack-ansible git tags 20.0.0 (f2ff7902)
I'm having trouble when running openstack-ansible setup-openstack.yml

```
Keystone Version 20.0.0
Failure On TASK [os_keystone : Create fernet keys for Keystone] *********************************************************************************************** 
fatal: [infra1_keystone_container-54825051]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "cmd": "/openstack/venvs/keystone-20.0.0/bin/keystone-manage fernet_setup --keystone-user keystone --keystone-group keystone", "msg": "[Errno 2] No such file or directory", "rc": 2}
```

Why is it missing keystone-manage file?

Then, I tried to run pip install requirement on keystone container but get the following error, here is the command I run on target host and its error

```
sudo lxc-attach --name infra1_keystone_container-54825051
cd /openstack/venvs/keystone-20.0.0
source /bin/activate
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Error:

```
(keystone-20.0.0) [root@infra1-keystone-container-54825051 keystone-20.0.0]# pip install -r requirements.txt
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 will reach the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 won't be maintained after that date. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.7. More details about Python 2 support in pip, can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support
Collecting keystone
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/4e/e6/22f5a2ee899c4cca1b20e07458ac72cb267ca5ad162f77affea942161fe9/keystone-16.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting ldappool
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a4/f2/e62f2f12a871b7bba62d446a20eec8362cae6fa4c55c3d73c587204dc551/ldappool-2.4.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting osprofiler
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/22/83/031090f9e6ecb58c520f5bda37a8260ffc953abe2751c435c429fd5d1a96/osprofiler-2.9.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting PyMySQL
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ed/39/15045ae46f2a123019aa968dfcba0396c161c20f855f11dea6796bcaae95/PyMySQL-0.9.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pyngus
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/58/b1/336b8f64e7e4efa9b95027af71e02cd4cfacca8f919345badb852381878a/pyngus-2.3.0.zip
Collecting python-memcached
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f5/90/19d3908048f70c120ec66a39e61b92c253e834e6e895cd104ce5e46cbe53/python_memcached-1.59-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting python-openstackclient
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/9b/09/c45ba3f9436f5b26691a4b1a309c959903bda6d8a5be04eec14f32db451a/python-openstackclient-5.2.0.tar.gz
Collecting systemd-python
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e8/a8/00ba0f605837a8f69523e6c3a4fb14675a6430c163f836540129c50b3aef/systemd-python-234.tar.gz
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /openstack/venvs/keystone-20.0.0/bin/python2 -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-QecSqm/systemd-python/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-QecSqm/systemd-python/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-install-QecSqm/systemd-python/pip-egg-info
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-QecSqm/systemd-python/
    Complete output (12 lines):
    Cannot find libsystemd or libsystemd-journal:

    Package libsystemd was not found in the pkg-config search path.
    Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libsystemd.pc'
    to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
    No package 'libsystemd' found

    Package libsystemd-journal was not found in the pkg-config search path.
    Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libsystemd-journal.pc'
    to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
    No package 'libsystemd-journal' found

    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
WARNING: You are using pip version 19.3; however, version 20.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

The target host machine is CentOS 7

Answer (score 0):

This error happens because there is a task on ansible install venv packages from repo_server, my repo_server is on lxc_container on infra1 host, it cant be reached, when the package search for repo on 10.0.0.246( infra1 host) it failed to get the repo inside infra1_host, because I need a load balance for it, So I added haproxy by following the openstack-ansible documentation, then repo_server now can be reached and the error is fixed.

Below solution shouldn't be used since error shouldnt happen if the installation is followed correctly.

I tried to overcome error of

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

I am missing systemd-devel, after running on keystone lxc container

```
sudo yum install systemd-devel
```

and manually pip install -r requirements.txt again ( I think this is not needed)
I passed that task

Note: I asked on openstack-ansible channel, then someone good help me and give tips that

> I need to be careful using pip like that, you've not use the
>   constraints / global-constraints files and
>
> in general we would never do that, use the ansible playbooks (and the related python_venv_build ansible role) to manage the contents of the virtualenvs